# Exam says "as to be impractical of study" is correct

Tags: tense, phrase-choice, negation, exam-questions

> Unlike a hurricane, which can be observed from within, a tornado is so small **that such a study has not been practical.**
>
> (A) that such a study has not been practical
>
> (B) that studying it that way has not been impractical
>
> (C) for such studies as this to have been impractical
>
> (D) as to not make such a study practical
>
> (E) as to be impractical of study

The correct solving of the above task from the test is supposed to be E. I do not understand why the adjective "impractical" is used in the sentence. It would make me sense when using "practical". I suppose that this sentence asserts that tornado is too small to be examined with a practical effect. Is the subordinate clause of purpose?

Comment: "The correct answer to the above question" - what question?

Comment: **A** simply repeats the cited context. **C** is very poor, if not ungrammatical. **D** is valid but "awkward", and **E** is a very unlikely, somewhat "archaic" construction. The only sensible choice if you don't like the original is **B**. But what is the question?

Comment: @FumbleFingers uh ... B means the opposite . . .

Comment: @StoneyB: I scarcely remember making that comment, but looking at it again now, I suspect I may simply not have noticed the fact that each alternative features *one* of the negations **[not] make, [not] been, [im]practical**. Except **B** - which has *two* such negations, effectively cancelling each other out.

Answer (score 1):

(E) is definitely not correct.

(A) is correct, and follows the pattern "so [adjective] that".

(B) is grammatically correct but has a double negative, which changes the meaning of the sentence. Since the sentence starts with:

> **Unlike** a hurricane, which **can** be observed from within...

the change is not likely to be correct.

(C) doesn't work after "so small". Also, "impractical" is negative, which changes the meaning of the sentence. A correct version would be:

> ...a tornado is **too** small for a study such as this to have been **practical**.

(D) might be correct grammar, but it sounds odd. This phrasing is more complicated than (A), and there's no reason to use it.

(E) is simply wrong. "[Adjective] of [noun]" is not correct English.

EDIT: There are a couple cases where "[adjective] of [noun]" is correct. If the noun is plural, you can make a superlative:

> Only the most heroic of knights are willing to fight a dragon.
>
> The King of France lived in Versailles, that most splendid of palaces.

There's also an archaic/poetic case, which is closer to (E):

> strong of body = strong, strong-bodied, having a strong body
>
> kind of heart = kind, kind-hearted, having a kind heart
>
> fleet of foot = fleet, fleet-footed, having a fleet foot = fast at running

But (E) doesn't fit this pattern. We wouldn't say that a tornado is "impractical-studied", or that it has an impractical study.

In the comments, stangdon gives a use of "impractical of collection" in a legal context. But all of the (few) uses of the phrase I found via Google appear to refer to the same law. The only uses of "impractical of study" on Google are this GMAT (?) question. So I think it's safe to say that (E) is not correct.

Comment: I disagree that E is "definitely not correct".  It's an unusual construction, but the meaning is perfectly clear, and it is not wrong.  It is found, for example, in the US Code of Federal Regulations: "This account shall be charged with any amounts which have been found to be impractical of collection."

Comment: I don't see any other uses of that phrase on Google, though. And there are no uses of "impractical of study" aside from references to this test question. I updated my answer with some other cases where "[adjective] of [noun]" is correct.

Comment: Which phrase exactly?  "impractical of Y" is, while slightly old-fashioned, not wrong.  Here's "[impractical of development](https://books.google.com/books?id=MUceAQAAIAAJ&lpg=PA137&ots=kF1LIu_e1z&dq=%22impractical%20of%22&pg=PA137#v=onepage&q=%22impractical%20of%22&f=false)".  Here's "[impractical of enforcement](https://books.google.com/books?id=fcQXAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA1031&ots=WqboWIDq_0&dq=%22impractical%20of%22&pg=PA1031#v=onepage&q=%22impractical%20of%22&f=false)".  Here's "[impractical of manufacture](http://www.netstate.com/states/symb/flags/wv_west_virginia_state_flag_v.htm)".

Comment: I was talking about "impractical of collection". The examples you're giving are in a legal context, the phrasing appears to be at least a century old, and there are very few pages on Google that contain them. I've never taken the GMAT, but it seems odd to have a standardized test for business school applicants require knowledge of archaic legal phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

A is correct as written, but wouldn't be the choice I would make if I wrote it.

The closest to my choice would be **E) as to be impractical of study** which sounds more polished, in my opinion.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct, and why the book's answer is wrong; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.